# Ransack order by association default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

```
Class Person 
 has_many:articles

end 

Class Articles
belongs_to: person
end
```

I want the person who posted recent articles. Thanks

```
q = q.ransack(name_age).order('articles.posted_at desc')
```

Comment: How do you initialize `q` and what is the content of `name_age`?

Comment: q = City.persons where citi is an another Model

Comment: And this should always only return persons that have recent articles?

Comment: it returns all Persons belongs to that citi

Comment: Yes I understand, but do you want to limit it to only persons with recent articles?

Comment: yes, only patients order by recent articles posted (onsearch and onrender by default)